# Using Json to add markers to Google Maps | API

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, getjson

I'm trying to plot markers on a google map using data from a Json Response. I have searched Stack Overflow for an answer all day but havn't managed to find a solution that has worked for me.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I am extracting the Lat & Lng but just can't put my finger on it. Below are my code and the Json, the Json is from an API.

Where is the error in my code?

### Script

```
<script>   
  function initialize() {
              var myOptions = {
                  zoom: 4,
                  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.397, 150.644),
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };

              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
              };

  function getLocations() {

      $.getJSON("URL", function (json) {

          $.each(json["resultsPage"]["results"]["event"], function(i, entry){
              addMarker(entry.location.lat,entry.location.lng);
          });
      });
  }

  function addMarker(lat,lng) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
          map: map,
          });
          markersArray.push(marker);
  }
  </script>
```

### Json Response

Told to request Json data by using the following code. If I leave the question mark at the end I get an invalid message when I run it through http://jsonlint.com as there is a question mark at the beginning of the Json. Taking that out appears to solve the problem but I'm not 100% sure that that is ok?

```
    $.getJSON("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?location=clientip&apikey={your_api_key}&jsoncallback=?",
    function(data){
    // data is JSON response object
    });
```

If I leave the question mark at the end I get an invalid message when I run it through http://jsonlint.com as there is a question mark at the beginning of the Json. Taking that out appears to solve the problem but I'm not 100% sure that that is ok?

When I view the code in debugger I get " SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' ", but this response is coming from an API so I am unsure what I can do about it?

```
    {
    "resultsPage": {
    "status": "ok",
    "results": {
        "event": [
            {
                "type": "Concert",
                "status": "ok",
                "performance": [
                    {
                        "artist": {
                            "displayName": "Arcade Fire",
                            "uri": "http://www.songkick.com/artists/66758-arcade-fire?utm_source=16289&utm_medium=partner",
                            "identifier": [
                                {
                                    "mbid": "52074ba6-e495-4ef3-9bb4-0703888a9f68",
                                    "href": "http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/artists/mbid:52074ba6-e495-4ef3-9bb4-0703888a9f68.json"
                                }
                            ],
                            "id": 66758
                        },
                        "billingIndex": 1,
                        "billing": "headline",
                        "displayName": "Arcade Fire",
                        "id": 29913729
                    },
                    {
                        "artist": {
                            "displayName": "Doody and Kami",
                            "uri": "http://www.songkick.com/artists/6334389-doody-and-kami?utm_source=16289&utm_medium=partner",
                            "identifier": [],
                            "id": 6334389
                        },
                        "billingIndex": 2,
                        "billing": "support",
                        "displayName": "Doody and Kami",
                        "id": 29913734
                    },
                    {
                        "artist": {
                            "displayName": "Leah Gordon",
                            "uri": "http://www.songkick.com/artists/6334394-leah-gordon?utm_source=16289&utm_medium=partner",
                            "identifier": [],
                            "id": 6334394
                        },
                        "billingIndex": 3,
                        "billing": "support",
                        "displayName": "Leah Gordon",
                        "id": 29913739
                    }
                ],
                "venue": {
                    "metroArea": {
                        "country": {
                            "displayName": "Canada"
                        },
                        "state": {
                            "displayName": "QC"
                        },
                        "displayName": "Montreal",
                        "uri": "http://www.songkick.com/metro_areas/27377-canada-montreal?utm_source=16289&utm_medium=partner",
                        "id": 27377
                    },
                    "lat": 45.5014288,
                    "displayName": "Phi Center",
                    "lng": -73.5564459,
                    "uri": "http://www.songkick.com/venues/1973969-phi-center?utm_source=16289&utm_medium=partner",
                    "id": 1973969
                },
                "popularity": 0,
                "location": {
                    "lat": 45.5014288,
                    "lng": -73.5564459,
                    "city": "Montreal, QC, Canada"
                },
                "start": {
                    "time": null,
                    "date": "2013-02-23",
                    "datetime": null
                },
                "displayName": "Arcade Fire with Doody and Kami and Leah Gordon at Phi Center (February 23, 2013)",
                "uri": "http://www.songkick.com/concerts/15215934-arcade-fire-at-phi-center?utm_source=16289&utm_medium=partner",
                "id": 15215934
            }
        ]
    },
    "perPage": 50,
    "page": 1,
    "totalEntries": 1
    }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

### Updated

Comment: You are using `json` variable as parameter and looping using `data`, `$.each(data["resultsPage"]["results"]["event"]` should be `$.each(json["resultsPage"]["results"]["event"]` at first.

Comment: Thanks... I think I've been staring at this screen for too long!

Comment: What is the question? "It doesn't work" is not enough information to go off of. Are you getting any error messages? Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: @gilly3 Perhaps not the clearest question but I was very tired when I wrote it! I'm just completely at a loss, I've spent hours making small changes to see if they have an effect and nothing... I hadn't been getting any errors but I am not getting one from my Json Response, "Unexpected ':'"... But this responce is coming from an API so not too sure what I can do about it?

Comment: mail me the code sirwanimayur@gmail.com

Comment: callback key is the key in which you json result comes wrapped around. you have to specify the a simple callbackKey Name and then your json result will come like callbackKeyName("jsonresult"); as $.getJson() is a GET Request on cross domain. so if you are mentioning ? there then the json response will come wrapped inside ?

Comment: from jQuery website: 
Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-quotes. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.

Comment: JSONP

If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

Comment: entry.location.lat,entry.location.lng??? i guess it should be entry.venue.location.lat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was able to reproduce you error.

The API which you are consuming doesn't support callback. you need to create a proxy and have to hit proxy from you code and your proxy will in turn call the api.

here is the code

index.html

```
        function getLocations() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://172.20.6.114/ontrack/data.php?callback=?",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(json){
                    $.each(json["resultsPage"]["results"]["event"], function(i, entry){
                        PlotMarker(entry.location.lat, entry.location.lng);
                    });
                },
                error: function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }

        function PlotMarker(lat, lon){
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
                map: gmap,
                draggable: false,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });
            markerLocations.push(marker);
        }
```

Code for data.php

```
<?
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?location=clientip&apikey={your_api_key}");

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $server_output . ');';
?>
```

Then it will show up.

Comment: Well this was awesome @SirwaniMayur

Answer (score 2):

Your `json` is invalid, `"resultsPage:" {` should be `"resultsPage" : {`, the colon is inside the double quotes, you can validate your `json` using [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/). Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5m7Kw/) using valid (edited) `json` which is printing `lat, lng` in the console.

Invalid json error from `jsonlint.com`

[image]

**Update:** You can also try this (for checking)

```
function myCallBack(data){
    console.log(data);
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?location=clientip&apikey={your_api_key}&jsoncallback=myCallBack"></script>
```

Comment: That response I posted earlier was taking from the documentation and as you know was wrong!!! Sorry for wasting your time. I've updated my answer with a real response, which I have ran through jsonlint.com and it came back as valid.

Comment: @Michael, Pleaase check the updated answer and see what you get, actually I'm still not sure what question mark your talking about.

Comment: at the end of the API request "&jsoncallback=?"... It's this that has been confusing me, with it I get an error but I kind of assumed it was needed or why else would they include it!

Answer (score 0):

The `&jsoncallback=?` **can be deleted safely**

Here's my view on that:

If you use the following code:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?location=clientip&apikey={your_api_key}&jsoncallback=?",
    function(data){
    // data is JSON response object
    });
```

Then, you don't need (probably) a json callback, since you are already using one after the comma (2nd parameter to `getJSON` function).

So you **can simply delete** the `&jsoncallback=?` from your URL and make it to `http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?location=clientip&apikey={your_api_key}`

Here's what is going on -

-- To facilitate JSONP (and Cross Domain AJAX request) you are sending a `callback` function to the URL

-- The Server then reads the `jsoncallback=XYZ` and then returns you the data **wrapped in** `XYZ` function call

-- So that you can define `XYZ` function in your JavaScript somewhere
   like the following:

```
function XYZ(jsonDATA) {
    // ... And do things Here. JSONP is cool !    
}
```

-- But Since you already have a functioning callback to the `getJSON` function, you don't need the `&jsoncallback=something` and can therefore delete it

**PS**: as a proof to above, try hitting the URL `http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?location=clientip&apikey={your_api_key}&jsoncallback=MyFunction` in your browser and you will get the following response in one line:

```
MyFunction({
    "resultsPage": {
        "status": "error",
        "error": {
            "message": "Invalid or missing apikey"
        }
    }
})
```

UPDATE:
To address your JavaScript error in comment --
Even though the response is a valid `JSON`, you are using the response as a `JavaScript` code, which is **invalid**

It would be a valid `JavaScript` code if you make it like this:

```
var myData = {
    "resultsPage": {
        "status": "error",
        "error": {
            "message": "Invalid or missing apikey"
        }
    }
}
```

But my point is, why are you checking the console error with this JSON data? Console is for `JavaScript`

Comment: Thankyou for your response, especially for trying to explain to me exactly what was going on and not just telling it was fine to drop it... I have ran it through JSONLINT and it is fine... But my console says there is an unexpected ':', you think it's alright tho?

Comment: @Michael, `console` is giving error because you are executing the JSON response as a JavaScript code. Its a valid JSON **but not** valid `JavaScript`. If you put `var abc = ` before your JSON in console, the error is gone !!

Comment: @Michael, also, you have accepted an answer which is an alternate solution. The answer says the API does not support callback, **which is wrong**. I gave you an example of sending `any_string_as_a_callback` to songkick, and the JSON comes wrapped in the callback. So it does support !!